# Convert 2 datatable to one table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have table Health:

```
Year   | Value1   | Value2
2015    Good       Good
2016    Bad        Good
2017    Bad        Bad
```

and table Money:

```
Year   | Money1   |Money2
2014    100        200
2015    300        null
2018    500        500
```

I want to make a tmp table look like this:
tmpTable

```
Year   |Value1   |Value2   |Money1   |Money2
2014    Null      Null      100       200
2015    Good      Good      300       Null
2016    Bad       Good      Null      Null
2017    Bad       Bad       Null      Null
2018    Null      Null      500       500
```

Can I do that in SQL Server?

Comment: With a regular outer join between the tables you can get that result

Comment: s , with left join u can  join these two tables

Answer (score 1):

Use 2 `LEFT` joins and use `UNION` to combine the result sets from both the `LEFT` joins.

**Query**

```
select t1.[Year], t1.[Value1], t1.[Value2], t2.[Money1], t2.[Money2]
from [Health] t1
left join [Money] t2
on t1.[Year] = t2.[Year]
union
select t1.[Year], t2.[Value1], t2.[Value2], t1.[Money1], t1.[Money2]
from [Money] t1
left join [Health] t2
on t1.[Year] = t2.[Year]
order by 1;
```

*[`SQL Fiddle demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1062a/1)*

Answer (score 0):

If Year is required in both tables, then you can use outer join between table Health and Money.

Answer (score 0):

It is the SQL query , u can refer this

```
  select A.Year,A.Value1,A.Value2, B.Money1,B.Money2 from Health A left join Money B on B.Year=A.Year
```

Comment: That is not exacly what i want. Table Health doesn't have year(2014 and 2018). If i use join on or something like Heath.Year = Money.Year, i won't get all year from table Health and Money

Comment: u can join with id of those instead of year. ( to get all values i used left join)  or u can use one more query and union it

Answer (score 0):

Create your desired table & use a join query to populate data.

`create table tmpTable(
Year   data_type(size),
Value1   data_type(size),
Value2   data_type(size),
Money1   data_type(size),
Money2   data_type(size)
);`

`insert into tmpTable (Year,Value1,Value2, Money1, Money2)
select t1.Year, t1.Value1, t1.Value2, t2.Money1, t2.Money2
from Health t1
inner join Money t2 on t1.Year = t2.Year`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with a full outer join instead of a left join.

select A.Year,A.Value1,A.Value2, B.Money1,B.Money2 from Health A full outer join Money B on B.Year=A.Year